# Take two string arguments and return a string with only the characters that are in both of the argument strings in python

Tags: python

```
def same_letters():

word1 = ''

word2 = ''

word1 = str(input("Please enter first word:"))
word2 = str(input("Please enter second word:"))

if word1 != word2:
    for letter in word1:
        for character in word2:
            word1 = word1.replace(character, "")


print(word1)
```

This is what I have so far; I want to be able to display the answer like so:

Please enter first word: space

Please enter second word: spot

sp

Instead when I run this program I get the opposite instead of getting the letters that are in both string arguments I get "ace" and if I switch it around I get "ot" I cannot for the life of me figure out how to display the same characters.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

You can use `set` and get their intersection.

```
def same_letters(s1,s2):
    return set(s1).intersection(s2)
```